# Как грамотно сделать роутинг на laravel?

Tags: php, маршрутизация, route

Всем привет!

У меня есть в БД меню как у всех с

```
id | parent_id | alias   | name
1  | 2         | odegda  | одежда
```

Я перехожу в Жакеты
В контроллер попадает ссылка типа   category/**odegda/zhenskaya/povsednevnaya/zhaketi**

Чтобы понять в какой категории я нахожусь и выдать пользователю правильно товары мне нужно эту ссылку разбить на части и найти каждую категорию и подкатегории.

Думаю в alias сразу хранить
odegda
odegda/zhenskaya
odegda/zhenskaya/povsednevnaya
odegda/zhenskaya/povsednevnaya/zhaketi

Подскажите пжл как лучше, ведь это меню я буду держать в кэше.
Или мне придется каждый раз формировать отдельно для каждой категории эти url в контоллере.

Comment: Вам придется делать динамический парсинг вашего адреса, примеры есть на англоязычном [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098060/dynamic-category-level-in-laravel), и конверсию результатов в подкатегории. Хотя, по сути, вам нужен только конечный результат - в этом случае вы можете определить уровень последней категории и сделать для этого уникальный ключ в виде "уровень-название" если есть такая возможность.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov спасибо за ответ. Просто вопрос в том что, мне каждый раз приходиться собирать URL для каждой категории. Может проще будет эти url держать в базе данных, т.к категорий будет 1800 и кэшировать это все. Или все такие правильно будет собирать URL их каждый раз!

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov еще видел вот такую штуку: место колонки parent_id создать другую и добавить туда #1#19#76#121 т.е id шники категорий. Как думаете такой подход?

Comment: Это уже вам виднее по вашим требованиям. Для ускорения да, предсобрать и держать в кэше до изменения структуры будет не лишним.